# Can we change the event calendar size dynamically on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar

I'm using [event calendar](https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar) plug-in on rails 2.3.8 and I need to know whether I can change the calendar size dynamically. For example in one page I need to show calendar in full page in another page I need to put that same calendar in small div. Is it possible with the event calendar plug-in ?

Comment: I don't understand your question quite right. You need the same calendar (month view) once on the full page, and the other time in a small div? How could that possibly work? Or do you need another view (only a week e.g.)?

Comment: Yes I need to show it another view But calendar size should be small. Normally if we need to change calendar size we have to change it in \public\stylesheets\event_calendar.css file. So I need to know whether I can change this value dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the real example, I can only give a sketch how it could possibly work:

Include the view in something like:

```
<div id="smallcal">
  <%= event_calendar %>
</div>
```

Add then a stylesheet that copies the rules of `event_calendar.css`, but modifies them like in the following example:

```
#smallcal > .ec-calendar { ... modified rules here ... }
```

So your modified rules will match better only for your variant where you want to make the calendar smaller. Perhaps it is possible to ensure that the calendar is smaller by including:

```
div#smallcal {
  width: 200px;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have found another way to solve this we can load what ever size event calendar by loading event calendar to required size div so in there it will automatically set.